# How to select a UITableView row that is not yet shown?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm not sure I'm phrasing my question correctly, so here's the details.
I'm using a UITableView to display the list of available fonts. When the list is dsiplayed,
only about 12 rows show at a time, so if the previously selected font is not yet show, I can't select it when first showing the view.

What I'd like is to have the cell selected and shown in the center of the list when the view appears. But since the UITableView only loads data as needed, this is the best I can get:

EDITED
I've tried this but it doesn't work (the cell is only briefly selected while scrolling):

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell==nil){
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        [cell.textLabel setText:[fontArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[fontArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size:16]];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
//select the cell/row if it matches the  current font
        if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:currentFontName]){
            cell.selected=YES;
        }
        NSLog(@"returning cell %@",cell.textLabel);
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in another thread - the problem is related to reusing cells. If I do not re-use cells, then everything works properly. Re-using cells also caused problems with multiple checkmarks appearing when only one item is selected. Thanks to those who contributed.

EDIT: If I should not be answering my own questions please tell me...but also tell me the proper way to resolve the question!

EDIT 2: This thread also helped
[UITableViewCell going black when selected programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576199/uitableviewcell-going-black-when-selected-programmatically)

Comment: FWIW, not reusing cells is a great way to create a table that scrollls horribly. It sounds like the bug was not reseting cell state when the cells were reused.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Make your comparison using `- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString`

1a - replace your test

```
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:currentFontName]){
    cell.selected=YES;
}
```

by

```
cell.selected = [cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:currentFontName];
```

1b - if you need to display your selected font you can do that before loading your TableView:

```
NSIndexPath * selFntPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [fontArray indexOfObject: currentFontName] 
                                              inSection: 0];

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: selFntPath 
                 atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                         animated: NO];
```

2 - Check that you do not unselect your cell in

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method.

This is a classic behavior in most sample codes.

**option**: you can keep the select property for user selection and toggle a specific control (ie checkmark using `accessoryType` property your cell) to show a system-selected row.

Comment: 1-ok, I've changed my posted code, 2-no de-selection. The problem that I can see is that the item isn't in the TableView until you scroll a few times and it gets populated. Once it's in the list, I get the rapid select/deselect described above...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the right approach but you can't test `NSString`s for equality by pointer comparison. You want `- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString` instead of `==`.

Comment: The isEqualToString part works (showing my lack of C knowledge) but the cell does not stay selected while scrolling. It is selected when it first comes into view, then de-selects. I've edited my post to more accurately reflect my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. I think you want `- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: That should center the table on the row you want. I'm not sure about the 'de-selects' part. It shouldn't lose the selected state that I can see ...

Comment: That doesn't work either as the item is not yet in TableView until you scroll a few times.

Comment: What doesn't work? `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` should ensure the desired row is on screen ...

Comment: The problem I see is that when the view first appears, the list has 12 (of 100) entries, so I can't select something that's not on the list yet (say, row 50).

Comment: Based on "What I'd like is to have the cell selected and shown in the center of the list when the view appears." I assume what you want is to first, figure out what index path should be selected by looking at your data, and then in your controller, at the right point (viewWillAppear, maybe), use scrollToRowAtIndexPath to make that row appear centered in the tableview (without the user having to scroll). The table view will call cFRAIP for that cell and your select code should fire.

Comment: Your statements are correct, but the solution does not work. I've tried several variants of selection in viewWillAppear and when the table is populated `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But since the list is being filled and re-filled as it scrolls, the desired item can only be selected when you scroll enough times. And then, it's only selected briefly. Try it - make an array with 100 items and then fill a table with the contents of the array and try to "pre-select" item #50, for example. I've ended up using a checkmark accessory instead (for now).