# Recompiling storyBoard makes uitableview black

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I am using a uitableview that I am filling programmatically implementing in the same *.m file  UIViewController  . It is working fine, but sometimes, when I recompile the storyBoard it is really strange because it shows the table completly black. I am using Interface builder to define the table and objective c to fill the table code.

When it is working fine if I exit an run agin from the phone the app keeps woking fine the problem appears if I make a change in the stroy board. It dosen´t matter if I am changing another view, sometimes it shows a black screen. I need to clean the project and build again.

I am using Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

I don´t see any error in the log screen and I don´t know if it is possible to see the story board compilation log.

What do you think? Thank you for your time.

Comment: share some code here

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4661641/3976183 answer. May Help !!

Comment: Finally I decided to do it programatically instead of using StoryBoard. It is quite strange but I think it is faster on this way because I use dinamic content.
Thank you for your help.